# Converting string to a valid JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

hey there i saw many questions about this topic but none of them fit my question.
i'm trying to use localStorage to store a user custom preferences, i try put an json object into a localStorage key and use it later on.
the object at the beginning looks like that:

```
 Object {test: "{a:"b",c:"d"}"}
```

the `JSON.parse` method returns an error, what i done is that:

```
var local_storage = getAll();
$.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(local_storage.test.substring(0,0).substring(0,local_storage.length,-1)));
```

the output is :

```
{a:"b",c:"d"}
```

but i can't use it as local_storage.test.a why is that and what is the solution for that?

thx for the help :)

**Edit!**

Thanks to @Oli Soproni B, the solution is:

```
var key = {a:"b",c:"d"};
var l = JSON.stringify(key);
localStorage.setItem('test',l);
var local_storage = $.parseJSON(localStorage.getItem('test'));
console.log(local_storage);
console.log(local_storage.a);
```

Comment: what is `local_storage.test.substring(0,0).substring(0,local_storage.length,-1)`?

Comment: why are you calling stringify and parse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// data
    var k = {a:"b", c: "d"};
    // stringify json
    var l = JSON.stringify(k);
    // set item to local storage
    localStorage.setItem('test', l);

    // get item to local storage and parse data
    var local_storage = $.parseJSON(localStorage.getItem('test'));

    console.log(local_storage);

    Object {a: "b", c: "d"}

    console.log(local_storage.a);

    prints b

// or use 
 var local_storage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('test'));
// in parsing the stringify json data
```

Comment: Since you use `JSON.stringify`, than you should also use `JSON.parse`, no need for jQuery here. jQuery would return same anyway: `if ( window.JSON && window.JSON.parse ) {return window.JSON.parse( data + "" );}`

Answer (score 1):

Localstorage stores string, not object. So you need to convert object to string while storing and converting it to object while retrieving.

**To store:**

```
localStorage.setItem("key",JSON.stringify(obj));
```

**To retrieve:**

```
obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(obj));
```

[**See DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/hiral/mqq28tta/)

Answer (score 0):

You used `Json.stringify`, because you need to store the data into localstorage as a string only.

you need to `parse` that again to `JSON` in order to use it as a JSON object,

---

but **not** like this

```
JSON.stringify(local_storage.test.substring(0,0).substring(0,local_storage.length,-1))
```

This tries to get a substring from your previously stored string, and again tries to stringify it.

---

You can get the stored string directly like this,

```
var local_storage = getAll();
var test=JSON.parse(local_storage.test);
```

And then use, as the test object, as  `test: {a:"b",c:"d"}`

Comment: i tried but it's returns an syntax error:Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token a